# Couldn't open `mt2e.cfg' error when installing a non-MikTeX package

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, windows

I am trying to add packages that are not within the MikTex repository to use in TexStudio. Particularly, I am trying to obtain the [mtp2lite](https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite?lang=en) package from CTAN.

I have created a custom root directory for packages that are not in MikTeX repository with the path `C:\Users\mihail\myextrapackages\tex\latex`.

In the MikTex console, I went under *Directories* -> *Root* -> *add* -> then selected the path : `C:\Users\mihail\myextrapackages`.
I have then performed

- a MikTex update,
- a Refresh file name database
- a Refresh font map files
- restarted MikTex and restarted TexStudio.

Now when I go into TexStudio and add the line `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` I receive the message

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get 
MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\mihail\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf

.log

Couldn't open `mt2e.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)
```

The log file contains

```
2021-02-01 16:19:53,708-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - this process (13808) started by 'pdflatex' with 
command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose mt2exa
2021-02-01 16:19:53,799-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2021-02-01 16:19:53,799-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer -- 
miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose mt2exa
2021-02-01 16:19:53,848-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex- 
enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose mt2exa
2021-02-01 16:19:54,326-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
2021-02-01 16:19:54,326-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer -- 
miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -g mt2exa 300
2021-02-01 16:19:54,331-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex- 
enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -g mt2exa 300
2021-02-01 16:19:54,760-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font mt2exa.
2021-02-01 16:19:54,760-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font mt2exa.
2021-02-01 16:19:54,760-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: 
2021-02-01 16:19:54,760-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: 
2021-02-01 16:19:54,760-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on and how this is fixable ?

Comment: Do you have, in your personal directory, a directory `C:\Users\mihail\myextrapackages\miktex\config` containing a personal `updmapcfg` with this line: `Map mtpro2.map`?

Comment: @Bernard thank your for the consideration. My `myextrapackages` directory contains only `tex\latex\mtp2lite` folder tree. I have manually created this directory by following the guidelines outlined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows.

Comment: To have fonts installed in your personal TeXMF directory found by the compiler of dvips, you need a personal `updmap.cfg` before refreshing the font map files. Presently, tthe system is trying to play withmetafont,, and of course it can't since there's no .mf file.

Comment: @Bernard This is valuable information, I appreciate it. I have created the file `updmap.cfg` containing only the line `Map mtpro2.map` and disabled the "hide extensions for known file types" in Windows such that this file is indeed a ".cfg" extension file. I have made the directories `myextrapackages\miktex\config` and placed the file within. I have then ran refresh font map files command in Miktex, but now the same problem still persists. Do you know perhaps which step I did wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't refresh the filename database first? (both as administrator and as user). This would mean your updmap.cfg can't be read.

Comment: @Bernard Unfortunately these 2 actions did not solve the problem.

Comment: The only way I can see would be   to use the command line (preferably from the directory containing you  personal updmap.cfg) at to launch the command `initexmf --mkmaps --verbose`. Also, after this check whether  the font is mentioned in `dvips.map` & similar files

Comment: The first command did not fix the problem. Also, my `C/Users/mihail/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/map/dvips/` , `C/Users/mihail/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fontname/` directories do not contain the file `mtpro2.map`. In fact, locate "*mtpro2.map" indicates this file is nowhere on my machine. The `dvips.map` file also does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119233/discussion-between-bernard-and-hitech-physics).